# Change String format [a, b, c] to interable list in python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, list, type-conversion

I received a JSON with a "code" and "list". I want to iterate for all names in list. But this list is as String, and I tried use *split()* but it is not working in this case.

```
jsonreceiced = request.get_json()
json_list = jsonreceiced['list']
#this returns [aaa, bbb, ccc]
#but is is still as a String
```

JSON:

```
{        'code': 'CODE',
         'list': '[aaa, bbb, ccc]'
}
```

I want do something like this:

```
for i in json_list:
     print i
     #Here I send SELECT to my data base
```

I create JSON in AndroidStudio like this:

```
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();        
    jo.put("code", etCode.getText().toString().trim());
    jo.put("list", userArrayList);
    #UserArrayList is my list of logins
```

Comment: Use `ast.literal_eval`  `ast.literal_eval('[1, 2, 3]')` returns `[1, 2, 3]`

Comment: @PatrickHaugh: won't work for `aaa` or other sequences of letters..

Comment: It may well be that you have obfuscated the data a bit too much. Are you saying you always have lists of letter sequences? That's not very useful, and doesn't give us much to work with. Could you give us a more realistic sample? It doesn't have to be real, just *representative*.

Comment: Maybe unrelated but how is this JSON created (and why is it not providing an array of strings but converting it to a single string)?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh it returns ValueError: malformed string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) like this:

```
>>> s = '[aaa, bbb, ccc]'
>>> [item.strip() for item in s[1:-1].split(',')]
['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
```

[`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) is used to remove trailing spaces from each item